# Mercurial: Incomplete central repository possible?

Tags: mercurial, repository

I want to realize the following setup:

AtWork:MercurialRepo <-> Internet:MercurialRepo <-> AtHome:MercurialRepo

Problem is the repository is several gigs. I already have the entire repo at home (through bundling->cdrom->unbundling). The thing is, I do not want to store the whole repository on the internet. Is there a way to temporarily exclude folders from versioning in order to push/pull only a subset of the repo I am working on through the internet? How do I best accomplish my goal? From time to time I would need to do the tedious bundling -> cdrom -> unbundling route, just to update everything else, but in general I do want to use the internet route and do not want to store the whole repo there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as you've found out by now you can't selectively clone some files from a repository. The best you can do is clone a subset of all branches; but you will get the entire past history of these branches, for all files in the repository. So, unless a lot of the big files are only known in some branches and not others, this won't help you.

Since your problem is the large size of files (rather than a long and bulky history), you probably need to break it down into several "subrepositories" of manageable size. Note that the subset you are interested in cloning must be a subrepository; cloning the main repo necessarily includes the subrepositories. The mercurial [subrepository documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Use_a_thin_shell_repository_to_manage_your_subrepositories) recommends that you make a trivial ("thin shell") main repo, and put all your project code in subrepositories.

Subrepositories are a complex solution, and are considered a "feature of last resort" by the mercurial team. It's a complex setup, there are various limitations (see the docs), and you'll have the extra complication of trying to convert your repo in a way that will preserve file history. So, it's worth considering ways to avoid this:

a) It would be best if you can avoid the middle copy of your repo; is there no way you can set up ssh access or a proxy so that your home repo can talk to your work repo directly? (Or vice versa; it's enough if *one* of the locations is able to contact the other).

b) You could carry the repo on a USB stick, as @vaclav's answer suggests.

c) Or maybe you should just bite the bullet and clone the entire repo on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to temporarily exclude folders from versioning in order to push/pull only a subset of the repo I am working on through the internet?

Not folders, but some parts of repo - yes

You can `push -b` (only some branch(es)) or `push -r` (revision with ancestors: for latest work it will be -r tip), but final size of transfer is heavy dependent from type of your DAG - in case of a lot of cross-branch merges you  probably skip only small part of changesets

Answer (score 0):

I have small idea, bit different from what you asked, but... 
If I have same issue, I would thing of using usb flash as whole repository (if you are about 10 or 20 gig it should be cheap). So at work you can copy, or clone whole repo to usb, pull new changes from it at home, and after your home working is done, push it to repo on flash, then pull it to repo at work(I use even temporary commits for undone work which I revert to working directory and strip, so I can continue where I ended).

But definitely easiest way, is to try get some connection to work servers, or to your machine at work. Or get bigger space for repo at internet. So, just another Ideat. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Is not really possible. The closest thing would be to use sub-repositories which will effectively allow you to have only part of your big repo on the net.